# Define icon for flatpak application

Tags: meson-build, flatpak

I am using gnome builder. I saw that in gnome music it is installed with

```
install_data(
    join_paths('icons/hicolor/scalable/apps', APPLICATION_ID + '.svg'),
    install_dir: join_paths(get_option('prefix'), get_option('datadir'), 'icons/hicolor/scalable/apps')
)
```

but it is not working doing only this.

Comment: It has to match the ID set in the manifest. If it does not, you can use `rename-icon` to rename it automatically.

Comment: I have also seen that the flatpak must be installed (not just built) so it is shown on the system.

Comment: Of course, the system doesn’t track local builds. You can pass an `--install` switch to `flatpak-builder` to simplify the process.